# How to prove or disprove that f is computable?

Tags: computability, proof-techniques

If $f(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ is a total function that for some constant $K$, $f(x_1,\dots, x_n) \leq K$ for all $x_1,\dots, x_n$ then $f$ is computable.

I want some hints on how to prove/disprove the above claim. This an exercise from the book [Computability, Complexity, and Languages](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122063821). As I didn't find the solutions to the exercises online, I want to see a formal solution of such problems, if possible.

Comment: Hint: try to find a counterexample using a well-known uncomputable (undecidable) set ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$ as follows.  Let $f(x) = 1$ if turing machine $x$ halts on itself as input and $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.  Then for all $x$, we have that $f(x) \leq 1$.  Yet, if $f$ is computable, then the Halting problem should be decidable.

Comment: If you'll excuse me, does it mean that f is not computable? Just to make sure I get it right.

Comment: Yes, the Halting problem is undecidable (this is something you should know if you ever try solving such exercises), and if $f$ being computable implies $\bot$ than $f$ cannot be computable.